# Tuple or out parameter for multiple return values?

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to return multiple parameter from a method in c#.I just wanted to know which one is better out or Tuple?

```
static void Split (string name, out string firstNames, out string lastName)
{
    int i = name.LastIndexOf (' ');
    firstNames = name.Substring (0, i);
    lastName   = name.Substring (i + 1);
}


static Tuple<string,string> Split (string name)
{
//TODO
}
```

Comment: There's a third option: Create a new type and return an instance of that.

Comment: None is better than the other, it's just a matter of preference

Comment: Tuples were added to the base library to support a functional programming style. In functional languages data is often passed around as tuples and lists. There is a downside to tuples and lists. Their members are not named and that is not good for readability if they are not used carefully. In general it is wise to keep data in specialized value objects if they stay around in the code for a while. That way the data gets an implicit meaning. If you keep data in a tuple you need to know that the first value is the first name and the second is the last name (or was it the other way around?).

Comment: Make that "explicit meaning"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is usually a (value) class hiding somewhere if you need to return more than one value from a method. How about a value class with the `Split()` method as ctor:

```
public class Name
{
    public Name(string name)
    {
        int i = name.LastIndexOf (' ');
        FirstNames = name.Substring (0, i);
        LastName   = name.Substring (i + 1);
    }

    public string FirstName {get; private set;}
    public string LastName {get; private set;}
}
```

Instead of

```
Split(name, out string firstName, out string lastName);
```

just do

```
Name n = new Name(name);
```

and access the first and last name via `n.FirstName` and `n.LastName`.

Comment: @Eric:+1 for the  innovative answer.

Comment: Does C# have implicit private setters these days?

Comment: You say "value class", yet you define a reference type (albeit with with getters only). Any reason you didn't make it a struct?

Comment: With "value class" I do not mean a struct (as opposed to a reference type), but a value object (http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ValueObject).

Comment: @Stephen: No, it does not. I did not actually feed this code into a compiler. I typed it right into the SO comment text box. Fixing...

Comment: @Stephen: This got me thinking. The setter should be private if you just write {get;}. That would be great and would make the property definition less verbose. Maybe this should be suggested for c#4++

Comment: @StephenSwensen it has implicit readonly properties now: `public string FirstName {get;}` is settable from the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is a necro I would like to add that, given the new features in C#9 and C#10, the tuple approach is more intuitive and takes advantage of anonymous types. Sometimes classes are just overkill - especially if this function is an extension method.

You can now use this signature syntax for tuples:

```
public (T1, T2, T3, .... TN) MyMethod(your parameters)
```

And also pre-name tuple entries: (Using your example)

```
static (string firstName, string LastName) Split (string name)
{ 
   int i = name.LastIndexOf (' ');
   return (name.Substring (0, i), name.Substring (i + 1));
}
```

If you'd like, you can also fill the result tuple data into existing variables:

```
string name = "Cat Dog";
string firstName, lastName;
(firstName, lastName) = Split(name);
/// firstName = Cat, lastName = Dog
```

Either of these implementations is very readable, maintainable, and modular - since you don't need to define a class.

My personal preference is that you should only define a class if there is an internal object state or necessary methods needed for the data - otherwise use a tuple.